# Issues in getting Touch Position in unity new input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, game-engine

I am Making a mobile game , and i am facing some issues in getting touch position properly using new input system in unity . this is what i am trynig to do .

I want to get the Tap position for a time at which a person holds the screen. else the value will be zero

i am getting the value in screen coordinates, and the values are correct. but when i convert the value using camera.main.screenToWorldPoint() to world coordinates i am getting value of only -16 approx . i dont now what is the problem , my screen point values are correct but world point values are -16 only , can some one help me solve this issue

here is my code :----

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerInputSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
Controlls controlls;
Controlls.TouchActions TouchControlls;
Controlls.KeyBoardActions KeyBoardControlls;

public FloatRefernce HorizontalAxis; // it is just my custom class


private void Awake()
{
    controlls = new Controlls();
    TouchControlls = controlls.Touch;
    KeyBoardControlls = controlls.KeyBoard;

    TouchControlls.TouchPress.performed += ctx => HorizontalAxis.Value = 
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(TouchControlls.TouchPosition.ReadValue<float>() , 0f)).x;

    TouchControlls.TouchPress.canceled += ctx => HorizontalAxis.Value = 0;

}



private void OnEnable()
{
    controlls.Enable();
    TouchControlls.Enable();
    KeyBoardControlls.Enable();
}
 private void OnDisable()
  {
    controlls.Disable();
    TouchControlls.Disable();
    KeyBoardControlls.Disable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vector3 The worldspace point created by converting the screen space point at the provided distance z from the camera plane.

The object axis and ScreenToWorldPoint axis are two different things.

[More information on the Unity Documentation about ScreenToWorldPoint.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)